# Parsing Data File with SQL

Tags: sql-server

My data is in a data feed where it looks like this ...

```
f|File_name|filedate

h|filedate|file_name|FName|Lname|UID

i|John|Doe|0001

i|jane|doe|0002

e|file_name

f|File_name|filedate

h|filedate|file_name|countryABR|Country|UID

i|USA|America|0001

i|CA|Canada|0002

e|file_name
```

The file starts with `f` in the first column then ends with an `e`. There are four separate files in on that are separated with these values. I am loading them into a SQL server database. I need find a way to separate them. Somehow reading that values between f and e to make a separate dataset for each.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a brute force approach. First insert the data into a staging table that contains one column called info and and identity ID. The table will also need two more columns called Recordtype and Parentid which will be null in the initial insert.  Then you pull out the record type form the first char of the record. Then you grab the id for the record of parenttype f and put it into the parentid. Then using a cursor you loop through the records and give each one the parentid of the record above it if the parentid is null. Once you have done this you now have the information to separate out the data into staging tables for each type of file.

The following code shows how to get the data grouped (i used a temp table to figure this out.)

```
create table #temp ( Id int identity, info varchar (max), RecordType char(1), parentid int)
insert into #temp (info)
values
('f|File_name|filedate'),

('h|filedate|file_name|FName|Lname|UID'),

('i|John|Doe|0001'),

('i|jane|doe|0002'),

('e|file_name'),

('f|File_name|filedate'),

('h|filedate|file_name|countryABR|Country|UID'),

('i|USA|America|0001'),

('i|CA|Canada|0002'),

('e|file_name')


update #temp
set recordtype = left(info,1), info = substring(info, 3,len(info) -3)

update #temp
set parentid = Id
where recordtype = 'f'

declare
@id int

DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id
from #temp 
order by ID

OPEN test_cursor


FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor
INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

update t
set parentid = t2.parentid
from #temp t
join #temp t2 on t2.id = t.id-1
where t.parentid is null
and t.id = @id

FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor
INTO @id
End
CLOSE test_cursor
DEALLOCATE Test_cursor

select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use C# or something like SSIS to parse and import the data?  This looks like something called a multi-line record layout; e.g., each data record actually consists of a number of distinct lines.

What I would do is either write a custom C# console app or a custom script within SSIS, and approach it something like this:

Read the file in, reading each line.  You want to accumulate until you reach a line with a "record" terminator, which would be the line where the first character is `e`.  So every time you have a line that starts with `f`, it's the start of a record, and `e` marks the end of a record.  While in that loop you accumulate in variables the different fields you want.  and after setting the variable on the `e` record then write to your SQL database a flattened version of the record into a single row.

This could probably be done in native SQL, too, but it seems like it would be a lot more work.